# WCF - how to get some channel identifier?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, channel, wcf

I need to identify a channel in my WCF service.

One way is to use Session.SessionID, but I can't seem to get the binding to work with sessions, and the session seems too much for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm just trying to write down history of a channel - what methods are being called, and to keep a hash of "channel ID's" that are currently active.

How can I get something like 'channel ID'? I know that the 'channel id' doesn't exist explicitly, but what are the workarounds?

Comment: What's the use case, what are you trying to achieve with this??

Comment: As I wrote - I'm trying to have a log in some history table based on channel Id that would track down what methods were called on each channel while it was opened. Also, to have a way to track what channels are opened (it's for some business logic).

Comment: If I am not mistaken author has no SessionMode so he cannot access OperationContext.Current to retrive session callback or any other info.

Comment: If IP is what you're looking for try to look at this: http://nayyeri.net/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nothing else does the trick, I 'tricked' it like this:

Add MessageHeader on the client side:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(cli.InnerChannel))
{
   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("MyHeader", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ""));

   string ret = cli.GetData(1);
}
```

In the "Name" property of the header I have the name of the header I want to pass, and I'm using the Namespace as the value-holder (since I can't seem to get to that 'value' of the header - it's not exposed as property?!). I do this on client side each time I create a service instance.

On service I read the header like:

```
var head = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "MyHeader");
string channelId = head.Namespace;
```

It's definitely a hack, but I'm out of time to create something more elegant, and this allows me to maintain 'channel id' the way I can control it... it's an ugly solution and I don't like it, so whenever someone finds something better I'd appreciate it...

*edit*: I tried using Outgoing/IncomingMessageProperties but that doesn't seem to work - it's nowhere to be found on server side... I'm probably missing something...

Comment: This is how you get the header value without hacking it via the namespace:
Guid myChannelID = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<Guid>("MyHeader", "http://example/my-header/");

Comment: @velijkov: All my Christmas' have come at once. ty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `string sessionID = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;`?

Comment: That doesn't exist if there's no session, which is my case - and I don't really want session.

Comment: Since you are not using sessions all you can do is just log down callback address, interface called and current time. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Callback address could be enough, but I'm not sure if it'll be validly identifying the user/channel? What if user has two applications that are using the service? There's no way to make distinction between them

Comment: Two applications cannot have same callback address

Comment: You're right (sorry for the comment in haste). But, the Callback  would require dual binding? I have one-way bindings like wsHttpBinding or basicHttpBinding...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `OperationContext.Current.Channel.GetHashCode()` might suit your purpose.

Comment: This always returns the same Hash value for each channel. Which leads me to conclusion that the channel doesn't hold anything that differentiates it from other channels.

Comment: ... or all your requests are being serviced on the same channel? What binding are you using?

Comment: basicHttpBinding - but even if I restart the app, the channel hash remains the same.

Comment: It seems from your answer that I misunderstood your original question: when you said "channel" I assumed you meant server-side channel, but it seems you meant client-side channel i.e. client proxy instance.